# Assign a value to a button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a chess program where each square is a button. Right now I am writing the command to make the pieces be able to move (which is executed when one is clicked) but it is telling me I am missing an argument (`squareposition`) when clicking.

How can I bind a value to each button within `Game.movepiece` ? 
here is the code I used to create the buttons:

```py
def drawboard(self):

    x=0
    y=0
    for column in range(self.n):
        self.changecolours()
        x=x+1
        y=0
        for row in range(self.n):
            y=y+1
            colour = self.colours[self.colourindex]
            position=(x,9-y)
            buttons=(tk.Button(self.boardframe, padx=10,  text=self.placepieces(position),  bg=colour,  borderwidth=2,  relief="solid", font=self.piecefont, command=lambda:Game.movepiece(position)  ))
            buttons.grid(column=(x-1), row=(y-1), sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S" )
            self.changecolours()
```

and here is the button's command function:

```py
    def movepiece(self, squareposition):
        if self.square==(-10,-10):
            self.square=squareposition
```

Comment: `def drawboard(self):` is a method from the `Game` class ?

Comment: No is one in my Layout class

Comment: `command=lambda pos=position :self.movepiece(pos)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Game.movepiece(position)` is calling the method at the class level, so `position` is used for the `self` parameter then `squareposition` is missing. You need to use an instance of `Game` to be able to call the method properly. Maybe you already instantiate it elsewhere in your code ?

Then as @Reblochon Masque  said you can replace the command with `command=lambda pos=position :self.movepiece(pos)`

```
def __init__():
    self.game = Game()

def drawboard(self):
    [...]
    position = (x,9-y)
    buttons = tk.Button(self.boardframe, padx=10,  text=self.placepieces(position),  
             bg=colour,  borderwidth=2,  relief="solid", font=self.piecefont, 
             command=lambda pos=position :self.movepiece(pos))
```